# Не отображаются иконки Font Avesome с символом - в названии в katrik SideNav

Tags: yii2

Не отображаются иконки Font Avesome с символом - в названии  в katrik SideNav.

Пробывал это решение
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350 ... 4ae24e7c7a
Не работает.

Comment: Ссылка на вопрос битая, исправьте пожалуйста. И приведите пример, будет очень полезен.

Answer (score 0):

Если я всё правильно понял, то Вам нужно в настройках `sideNav` при отображении указать параметр:

`'encodeLabels' => false,`